# При вызове /calendar в python, с использованием python-calendar current_shown_dates not defined

Tags: python, telegram, бот, calendar

Код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['calendar'])
def get_calendar(message):
    now = datetime.datetime.now() #Текущая дата
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    date = (now.year,now.month)
    current_shown_dates[chat_id] = date #Сохраним текущую дату в словарь
    markup = create_calendar(now.year,now.month)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пожалйста, выберите дату", reply_markup=markup)
```

Консоль:

```
current_shown_dates[chat_id] = date #Saving the current date in a dict
NameError: name 'current_shown_dates' is not defined
```

Comment: ну одна из явных причин в отсутствии самого словаря для сохранения, Попробуйте сделайте `current_shown_dates = {};  current_shown_dates[chat_id] = date `

Answer (score -1):

Необходимо создать словарь прежде, чем записывать в него значения.

```
def get_calendar(message):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()  # Текущая дата.
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    date = (now.year,now.month)

    # Добавлено создание словаря.
    current_shown_dates = {}

    current_shown_dates[chat_id] = date  # Сохраним текущую дату в словарь.
    markup = create_calendar(now.year,now.month)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пожалуйста, выберите дату", reply_markup=markup)
```